# UIScrollView scrolling stops working after adding width and height constraints to its content

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have an `UIImageView` within a `UIScrollView`, and scrolling works fine when I add `trailing`, `leading`, `top` and `bottom` constraints to the `UIImageView`. However, the image in the `UIImageView` can be very large, and I want it to always display as a *646x537* fixed size image regardless of the picture assigned to it.

Without any extra constraint, the `UIScrollView` grows as large as the original picture. So, I added `width` and `height` constraints to the `UIImageView`, but then, `UIScrollView` scrolling is not working anymore, even when the content is still larger than the the *view controller*.

[image: Xcode navigator]

[image: Xcode storyboard]

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong one. This one determines the content size of your `UIScrollView`, and therefore whether it scrolls or not. It should be set to +50, to be consistent with the other constraints.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, auto layout and scroll views is a tricky combination. It took me a couple of projects to get it right.